# How to determine which tasks completed first using Task.WaitAny()?

Tags: c#, multithreading, task

In this code, you always get the same results. I don't know why the IDs of these tasks are 1,3,4.

If you put a breakpoint at `int index = Task.WaitAny(tasks);` and wait for 2 seconds, you get good results. The results in the first case are different and the IDs are equal to 1, 2, 3.

```
public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var tasks = new Task[3];
        var rnd = new Random();
        for (int ctr = 0; ctr <= 2; ctr++)
            tasks[ctr] = Task.Run( () => Thread.Sleep(rnd.Next(500, 3000)));

        try 
        {
            int index = Task.WaitAny(tasks);
            Console.WriteLine("Task #{0} completed first.\n", tasks[index].Id);
            Console.WriteLine("Status of all tasks:");

            foreach (var t in tasks)
                Console.WriteLine("   Task #{0}: {1}", t.Id, t.Status);
        }
        catch (AggregateException) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("An exception occurred.");
        }
    }
}

// The example displays output like the following:
//     Task #1 completed first.
//     
//     Status of all tasks:
//        Task #3: Running
//        Task #1: RanToCompletion
//        Task #4: Running
```

Comment: [Seems to work fine](https://rextester.com/PYARK44833)

Comment: or https://dotnetfiddle.net/67AaRZ

Comment: But why always win first? and why id is +1 for other?
Just debug 10 times, and you always get the same result.

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.id) of `Task.Id`, it says:

> Task IDs are assigned **on-demand** and **do not necessarily represent the
>   order in which task instances are created**. Note that although
>   collisions are very rare, task identifiers are not guaranteed to be
>   unique.

(emphasis mine)

So, using `Task.Id` for this purpose (i.e., checking what task is completed first) is in no way reliable. What you should do is rely on the index of the element in the array instead. In this case, your code would look something like this:

```
var tasks = new Task[3];
var rnd = new Random();
for (int ctr = 0; ctr <= 2; ctr++)
    tasks[ctr] = Task.Run(() => Thread.Sleep(rnd.Next(500, 3000)));

try
{
    int index = Task.WaitAny(tasks);
    Console.WriteLine("Task #{0} completed first.\n", (index + 1));
    Console.WriteLine("Status of all tasks:");

    for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
        Console.WriteLine("   Task #{0}: {1}", (i + 1), tasks[i].Status);
}
catch (AggregateException)
{
    Console.WriteLine("An exception occurred.");
}
```

That way, you get different results when you run the program multiple times. You can [try it online](https://rextester.com/HXC10320).

For more information about the behavior of `Task.Id`, you may read [Stephen Cleary](https://stackoverflow.com/users/263693/stephen-cleary)'s article: [A Few Words on Task.Id (and TaskScheduler.Id)](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/03/a-few-words-on-taskid-and.html).

Comment: Ok, but in this program id for start is 1,2,3, and after "int index = Task.WaitAny(tasks);" it change on 1,3,4. 
This write again always Task #1 completed first. Never change the result.

Comment: The whole point of this answer is to tell you not to use `Task.Id` for this purpose _because it doesn't work_. Why are you still using it and trying to make it work?

Comment: _"This write again always Task #1 completed first"_ What do you mean by "this"? If you mean this exact code that I wrote in my answer, then it should display different results if you run it multiple times. Did you try running it online using the link I provided?

Comment: Ok. My first question was dont I understand it or doesnt it work. Then i ask why this work like this. No one wrote it dont work. Thanks for help me.

Comment: Ok it work, sorry i checked it 3 times and get #1. So a problem is ID which dont work good.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using Microsoft's Reactive Framework (aka Rx) - NuGet `System.Reactive` and add `using System.Reactive.Linq;` - then you can do this:

```
var rnd = new Random();

IObservable<int> query =
    from n in Observable.Range(0, 3)
    from _ in Observable.Start(() => Thread.Sleep(rnd.Next(500, 3000)))
    select n;

IDisposable results =
    query.Subscribe(n => Console.WriteLine("Observable #{0} completed.", n));
```

I get this kind of output:

```
Observable #0 completed.
Observable #2 completed.
Observable #1 completed.
```

It's generally more powerful and more expressive than tasks.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I just tried understand how Tast work, and it looked like bug. Which exactly is.

Comment: @mdlejtecole - What's the bug?

Comment: Above you have the results. if you use id you have always bad results. ID for Task which arent ended is +1. Always win Task with id 1.

Comment: @mdlejtecole - It's not a bug, it's how it's been designed.

Comment: So it is total usless, you cant check with task was ended first by ID, you cant refer by ID, because they are different.Do you know what example to use this id?